# How to set up user interpretation for interpreters when running zeppelin in a docker image?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I'm setting up a docker image on the basis of the [zeppelin docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/zeppelin/). Now I'm packing my own configuration into my own docker image. I've got it connected to LDAP for logging in and for user impersonation. Like [this](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/usage/interpreter/user_impersonation.html), overriding the ZEPPELINIMPERSONATECMD in zeppelin-env.sh.

Running `whoami` with the sh interpreter works fine now. And running `id` also shows all the correct user information from ldap.

However when I switch the python interpreter to the isolated per user setting and turn on user interpretation it will fail with a ImportError[1] response in the note itself. The server logging looks like this[2], I replaced my user name with `user_name`.

I've tried not overwriting the the ZEPPELINIMPERSONATECMD in zeppelin-env.sh. That will just result in a runtime exception[3] when running anything.

I've tried copying the /zeppelin/interpreter/python/py4j-0.9.2/src/py4j folder to /tmp but that will just result in `python not responding` after 10 seconds.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to run the python interpreter as the logged in user?

[1]:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_python-702917387527627656.py", line 20, in <module>
    from py4j.java_gateway import java_import, JavaGateway, GatewayClient
ImportError: No module named py4j.java_gateway
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_python-702917387527627656.py", line 20, in <module>
    from py4j.java_gateway import java_import, JavaGateway, GatewayClient
ImportError: No module named py4j.java_gateway
python is not responding
```

[2]:

```
 INFO [2019-08-14 15:13:14,716] ({pool-2-thread-2} ShellScriptLauncher.java[launch]:48) - Launching Interpreter: python
 INFO [2019-08-14 15:13:14,727] ({pool-2-thread-2} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[start]:115) - Thrift server for callback will start. Port: 40221
 INFO [2019-08-14 15:13:14,738] ({pool-2-thread-2} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[start]:190) - Run interpreter process [/zeppelin/bin/interpreter.sh, -d, /zeppelin/interpreter/python, -c, 172.17.0.3, -p, 40221, -r, :, -u, user_name, -l, /zeppelin/local-repo/python, -g, python]
 INFO [2019-08-14 15:13:16,400] ({pool-7-thread-1} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[callback]:123) - RemoteInterpreterServer Registered: CallbackInfo(host:172.17.0.3, port:40445)
 INFO [2019-08-14 15:13:16,440] ({pool-2-thread-2} RemoteInterpreter.java[call]:168) - Create RemoteInterpreter org.apache.zeppelin.python.PythonInterpreter
 INFO [2019-08-14 15:13:16,540] ({pool-2-thread-2} RemoteInterpreter.java[call]:168) - Create RemoteInterpreter org.apache.zeppelin.python.IPythonInterpreter
 INFO [2019-08-14 15:13:16,544] ({pool-2-thread-2} RemoteInterpreter.java[call]:168) - Create RemoteInterpreter org.apache.zeppelin.python.PythonInterpreterPandasSql
 INFO [2019-08-14 15:13:16,545] ({pool-2-thread-2} RemoteInterpreter.java[call]:168) - Create RemoteInterpreter org.apache.zeppelin.python.PythonCondaInterpreter
 INFO [2019-08-14 15:13:16,547] ({pool-2-thread-2} RemoteInterpreter.java[call]:168) - Create RemoteInterpreter org.apache.zeppelin.python.PythonDockerInterpreter
 INFO [2019-08-14 15:13:16,549] ({pool-2-thread-2} RemoteInterpreter.java[call]:142) - Open RemoteInterpreter org.apache.zeppelin.python.PythonInterpreter
 INFO [2019-08-14 15:13:16,549] ({pool-2-thread-2} RemoteInterpreter.java[pushAngularObjectRegistryToRemote]:436) - Push local angular object registry from ZeppelinServer to remote interpreter group python:user_name:
 WARN [2019-08-14 15:13:27,703] ({pool-2-thread-2} NotebookServer.java[afterStatusChange]:2316) - Job 20190814-151311_1784127416 is finished, status: ERROR, exception: null, result: %text Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_python-4627212054430132450.py", line 20, in <module>
    from py4j.java_gateway import java_import, JavaGateway, GatewayClient
ImportError: No module named py4j.java_gateway

%text Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_python-4627212054430132450.py", line 20, in <module>
    from py4j.java_gateway import java_import, JavaGateway, GatewayClient
ImportError: No module named py4j.java_gateway

%text python is not responding
 INFO [2019-08-14 15:13:27,713] ({pool-2-thread-2} VFSNotebookRepo.java[save]:196) - Saving note:2EJWQC1Y4
 INFO [2019-08-14 15:13:27,715] ({pool-2-thread-2} SchedulerFactory.java[jobFinished]:120) - Job 20190814-151311_1784127416 finished by scheduler org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter-python:user_name:-shared_session
```

[3]:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Cannot assign requested address


    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.start(RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java:205)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.ManagedInterpreterGroup.getOrCreateInterpreterProcess(ManagedInterpreterGroup.java:64)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getOrCreateInterpreterProcess(RemoteInterpreter.java:111)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.internal_create(RemoteInterpreter.java:164)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:132)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:299)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:407)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by adding:

> export PYTHONPATH=/zeppelin/interpreter/python/py4j-0.9.2/src

in zeppelin-env.sh.

After that the interpreter ran fine.